# SQL Server 2012 - Conversion Fails for No Possible Reason with Views

Tags: sql-server-2012, view

I have a view setup as

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.my_data_view
AS
SELECT * from dbo.my_used_data (NOLOCK)
UNION
SELECT * from dbo.my_unused_data (NOLOCK)
go
```

I currently don't have anything in `my_unused_data` table. But I expect any query made to work just fine. the following is my query:

```
select * from my_data_view where code = '5E7230893312001084789839'
```

The query is failing with the message:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '8E2230893319020101078983' to data type int.
```

This doesn't make any sense. `my_used_data` and `my_unused_data` tables have the identical schema and types so nothing can go wrong there. What I have found out is that when I have data in `my_unused_data`. It works fine;Otherwise it fails. Is it something special with the views or what?

Comment: Do you know where '8E2230893319020101078983' comes from? It is not your where condition.

Comment: @FlorianHeer     it comes from a parameterised query - That's irrelevant. The problem is that the view should simply return me an empty resultset. I can deal with it.

Comment: Are you sure, the column "code" in table dbo.my_used_data is of type nvarchar and not int?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the order of the columns where swapped for column no. 3 and 4 for `my_unused_data` that messed things up. I didn't realise that SQL server assumes that ordering of the column is correct when dealing with SELECT * UNION SELECT * queries